# How to apply compactMap to two combined publishers

Tags: swift, combine

Assume the two following publishers:

```
var firstFeed = PassthroughSubject<Int?, Never>()
var secondFeed = PassthroughSubject<Int?, Never>()
```

How do I create a subscription where the sink is called when the two feed provide two none-nil values. This is what I have so far, but it seems ugly.

```
   let sub = firstFeed
        .compactMap{$0}
        .combineLatest(secondFeed.compactMap({$0}))
        .sink { firstValue, secondValue in
            print("we sunk with \(firstValue), \(secondValue)")
        }
```

With the following stream of data:

```
    firstFeed.send(1)
    secondFeed.send(nil)
    secondFeed.send(2)
    firstFeed.send(nil)
    firstFeed.send(3)
    firstFeed.send(nil)
    secondFeed.send(nil)
    firstFeed.send(nil)
    secondFeed.send(nil)
    secondFeed.send(4)
    firstFeed.send(nil)
    secondFeed.send(nil)
    firstFeed.send(5)
    secondFeed.send(6)
    secondFeed.send(nil)
    firstFeed.send(nil)
    firstFeed.send(7)
    firstFeed.send(nil)
    secondFeed.send(8)
```

I get this output:

```
we sunk with 1, 2
we sunk with 3, 2
we sunk with 3, 4
we sunk with 5, 4
we sunk with 5, 6
we sunk with 7, 6
we sunk with 7, 8
```

ideally I would want something like this:

```
    let sub = firstFeed
        .combineLatest(secondFeed)
        .compactMap{?}
        .sink { firstValue, secondValue in
            print("we sunk with \(firstValue), \(secondValue)")
        }
```

I'm not sure what goes into the compact map when two publishers are combined...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be honest, I don't really think your first way is "ugly". I would just use it as it is.

If you really want to use `compactMap` on a publisher of pairs, well... `compactMap` wants you to transform the given element to `nil` to mean that you want this element to be removed. For mapping `T?` to `T`, this is easy, because the things we want to remove are exactly `nil`!

However, you want to map from `(Int?, Int?)` to `(Int, Int)`, so we need to produce a nil value of `(Int, Int)?` when we find either of the values in the pair is nil, and return the pair, with its elements unwrapped, otherwise.

In short, you are trying to convert from a `(Int?, Int?)` to a `(Int, Int)?`

```
.compactMap { x, y -> (Int, Int)? in
    guard let first = x, let second = y else { return nil }
    return (first, second)
}
```

You can also do it in just one expression:

```
.compactMap { first, second in
    first.flatMap { x in second.flatMap { y in (x, y) } }
}
```

There is no built in way to conveniently turn `(Int?, Int?)` into `(Int, Int)?`, but I have found [this proposal](https://forums.swift.org/t/add-unwrap-function-to-tuple-for-unwrapping-multiple-optionals/26956) that suggest this conversion should be a built in function.

You can write such a function yourself to make this look a bit prettier:

```
func unwrap<A, B>(pair: (A?, B?)) -> (A, B)? {
    pair.0.flatMap { a -> (A, B)? in
        pair.1.flatMap { b -> (A, B)? in
            (a, b)
        }
    }
}

let sub = firstFeed
    .combineLatest(secondFeed)
    .compactMap(unwrap)
    .sink { firstValue, secondValue in
        print("we sunk with \(firstValue), \(secondValue)")
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `filter` and `map` to skip nil values:

```swift
let sub = firstFeed
    .combineLatest(secondFeed)
    .filter { $0.0 != nil && $0.1 != nil }
    .map { ($0.0!, $0.1!) }
    .sink { firstValue, secondValue in
        print("we sunk with \(firstValue), \(secondValue)")
    }
```

, or `compactMap` to combine the `filter` and `map` into one, but maybe less readable, condition:

```swift
let sub = firstFeed
    .combineLatest(secondFeed)
    .compactMap { $0.0 != nil && $0.1 != nil ? ($0.0!, $0.1!) : nil }
    .sink { firstValue, secondValue in
        print("we sunk with \(firstValue), \(secondValue)")
    }
```